How to get openmp to generate avx2 instructions?
I wrote the following sum function. Compiling with:
g++ -g -O3 -march=core-avx2 sum.cpp

#include <omp.h>

float sum(const float* a, int n) {
    float total_sum = 0.0f;

#pragma omp simd reduction(+:total_sum)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        total_sum += a[i];
    }

    return total_sum;
}

The code generated uses xmm registers, but not ymm. Is there any way to get it to generate avx2 code using the ymm registers?
Similarly, what is the option allowing generation of avx512?

You forgot to add the critical flag -fopenmp-simd. This flag fix the issue. The current generated code uses xmm registers because it is not vectorized at all. Without OpenMP flags, OpenMP directives are ignored.

As for Avx-512, the target CPU does not support it. It will be used if you target a CPU supporting it. Alternatively, you can use the flag -mavx512f (and other variants of AVX-512 which is split in many parts)

Use -march=native to let the compiler use all features supported by the CPU in the machine it's compiling on.  The default is to make a portable binary that will run on any x86-64.
